Why do I get `ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }` when parsing what seems to be a valid integer string?
I am writing a program that reads a file line-by-line, extracts all digits contained in each line (ignoring any other characters), interprets the resulting digits in each line as an integer, and prints the sum of the integers.
The file is the following:
1abc2
pqr3stu8vwx
a1b2c3d4e5f
treb7uchet

And the expected output is 12 + 38 + 12345 + 7 = 12402
This is my attempt:
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("day1.txt").expect("Should have been able to read the file");
    const ARRAY_REPEAT_VALUE: String = String::new();
    let mut number_array: [String; 4] = [ARRAY_REPEAT_VALUE; 4];
    let mut counter: usize = 0;

    for i in contents.lines() {
        let mut on_to_next: bool = false;
        let mut num1: char = '\0';
        let mut num2: char = '\0';
        for j in i.chars() {
            if j.is_numeric() {
                if on_to_next {
                    num2 = j;
                } else {
                    num1 = j;
                    on_to_next = true;
                }
            }
        }
        number_array[counter] = format!("{}{}", num1, num2);
        counter += 1;
    }

    let mut total: i32 = 0;
    for p in number_array {
        print!("-{}-\n", p.trim());
        let converted_number: i32 = p.trim().parse().unwrap();
        total += converted_number;
    }
    print!("{}", total);
}

But it fails with:
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:35:54:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }

Why does it happen, and what can I do to fix this problem?

Tip: Don't use sentinels such as '\0' to indicate missing values, use Option::None. Then you don't run into issues like this.

If you alter your debugging line to use debug output ({:?}):
print!("-{:?}-\n", p.trim());

You will notice that the last string slice you're trying to parse contains a nul character:
-"12"-
-"38"-
-"15"-
-"7\0"-

Your .trim() here is doing exactly nothing; instead you could use .trim_end_matches('\0') to fix the immediate error:
let converted_number: i32 = p.trim_end_matches('\0').parse().unwrap();

There may still be other bugs in the program that make its output incorrect, but this fixes the specific error you are seeing.

How you process each line two digits at a time seems to be causing issues for the a1b2c3d4e5f and treb7uchet lines.
Instead, how about using a more functional approach:
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("src/day1.txt").expect("Failed to read the file");
    let total: i32 = contents
        .lines()
        .filter_map(|line| {
            line.chars()
                .filter(|c| c.is_numeric())
                .collect::<String>()
                .parse::<i32>()
                .ok()
        })
        .sum();
    println!("Total sum: {}", total);
}

Output:
Total sum: 12402


If you're willing to dispense with the "couldn't parse" warning, you can simplify this quite a lot more. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3a0c9c213ce4b90cf16c394add492d4

Note I made the code even simpler while you were editing your question, the link in my previous comment has been updated. :)

Today I learned.

I don't think it's likely to matter here (I know what OP is working on and the input is always ASCII) but generally, if the goal is to parse a number you should use is_ascii_digit to filter, because is_numeric matches non-ASCII Unicode glyphs that are in the numeric category, which parse is going to choke on.

And here is a version that avoids the intermediate String allocation and parsing.
